# git でブランチのマージを実行するとメッセージが表示されたまま動かない

Tags: git

gitでブランチをマージさせたかったのですが、以下のメッセージが表示されました。
この表示のまま動きません。どうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:xxx/awesome

first
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim
```

Answer (score 9):

何かエラー等が発生しているわけではなく、"コミットメッセージを入れろ" と git がエディタ (Vim) を起動している状況です。
コミットメッセージを入れてください。ないしは入れずに終了（コミットを中断）してください。

邦訳

```
# このマージが必要である理由を説明するコミットメッセージを入力してください。
# （更新されたupstreamをトピックブランチにマージする場合は特に）
#
# シャープで開始されている行は無視されます。空のメッセージを入力するとコミットは中断されます。

vim を終了するには :quit を入力してください。
```

---

現状 Vim で仮コミットメッセージが開いている状態です。

- Vim のコマンド操作 `:quit` とだけすると今回のコミットが中断されます。
- 何らかのメッセージを入力後 `:quit` でそのメッセージとともにコミットされます。